# Duplicate Output with TestContext.WriteLine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I've made an "ordered test" in VS 2008 which executes 4 tests.  One of the `TestMethod` tests it runs has several writeline statements, like this:

```
TestContext.WriteLine("One");
TestContext.WriteLine("Two");
TestContext.WriteLine("Three");
```

The output I receive in the "Additional Information" of the results shows this output:

> One 
> Two 
> Three 
> One 
> Two 
> One 
> Two

I don't think the test method is running multiple times.  I think the writeline output is simply being buffered in some bizarre way.  **How do I fix this?**

I get this problem with any test method that has `TestContext` writeline statements (at least when invoked from an ordered test).

Comment: Have you tried trimming down your tests until only the WriteLine calls are left? That’s usually a good way to discover which part is causing this.

Comment: If I have only one test, it still has this problem. I don't see how else to interpret the result, other than mstest is buggy or I don't understand the intent of the TestContext.writeline statement.

Comment: I often use Console.WriteLine in my MSTests. Try that instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786884/debug-writeline-doesnt-work-from-within-unit-tests