# How to write to Console.Out during execution of an MSTest test

Tags: c#, console, mstest, watin

***Context:***
We have some users reporting issues with a file upload feature in our web application. It only happens occasionally and without any special pattern. We have been trying to figure it out for a long time, adding debug information anywhere we can think it might help, crawling the logs etc, but we have not been able to reproduce or figure it out.

***Problem:***
I'm now trying to reproduce this by using MSTest and WatiN to repeat the operation that is supposed to fail a large number of times (several hundreds). Just to have a clue about how far in the loop the test has gotten, I want to print something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Uploaded file, attempt {0} of {1}", i, maxUploads));
```

This does however not appear in the Output window. Now I know that you'll get the console output in the test results (as well as what you output from `Debug.Writeline` etc), but this is not available until *after* the test has finished. And since my test with hundreds of repetitions could take quite some time, I'd like to know how far it has gotten.

***Question:***
Is there a way I can get the console output in the Output window *during* test execution?

Comment: If you look for a way to print to the test result output:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4787047/621690

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The Console output is not appearing is because the backend code is not running in the context of the test.

You're probably better off using `Trace.WriteLine` (In System.Diagnostics) and then adding a trace listener which writes to a file.

[This topic from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx) shows a way of doing this.

---

According to Marty Neal's and Dave Anderson's comments:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Diagnostics;
>
> ...
>
> Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
> // or Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
> Trace.WriteLine("Hello World");
> ```

Comment: so basically, 
`Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));`
`Trace.WriteLine("Hello World");`

Comment: Nice, I like it. To get around this I've used log4net with a filelogger. You'll have to change your calls from Console.WriteLine to Logger.Info(...)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm finding that the suggestion by @Martin Neal sends both `Trace.WriteLine()` and `Console.WriteLine()` output to the **Test Results View**, *not* the **Output View**. (And note that in the **Test Results View**, it may be necessary to add the **Output (Stdout)** column by right-clicking and selecting **Add/Remove Columns...**.) But, perhaps I'm still not seeing output in the **Output View** means that I'm missing something...

Comment: `Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());` is sufficient and then Show output from Debug in output window.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The information I send to `Trace.WriteLine` appears only in the test output window, as @DavidRR says.

Comment: I was struggling to actually find the output in VS2017... TestExplorer window -> Click on an individual test -> If the test had ouput, in the detail window under the elapsed time there is the word "ouput" which is a link to a new window.

Comment: @MikeWalsh yes and have you noticed how you can't select part of the text to copy it out?  Absolutely crazy IMHO...

Comment: Basically, you're wanting to make assertions about things that are normally logged out to the console. Using this answer, and combining it with a [memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149993/1520850) will essentially allow you to do that. Other answers on here cover this in different ways

Comment: if you are using xunit checkout this link https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

Comment: If you're using Xunit, just take ITestOutputHelper in through the ctor and call WriteLine on it. Took a while before I found out how to write during integration testing, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Should this work when I run the test as well, or only when I debug it?

Comment: IMO, the first part of the answer ("adding a trace listener which writes to a file.") should be removed, because the 2nd part is the actual answer. I did almost ignore the answer because I thought, the answer was just about writing to a file what I'm not interested in. @AndrasZoltan

Answer (score 85):

Use the `Debug.WriteLine`. This will display your message in the `Output` window immediately. The only restriction is that you must run your test in `Debug` mode.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Time {0}", DateTime.Now);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
    Debug.WriteLine("Time {0}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: requires `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: Don't use DateTime.Now. It's better to use Stopwatch (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. When I run the test the Output Window immediately switches to Build and nothing is sent to Debug. Your thoughts?

Comment: @InteXX make sure you click "Debug the test", not "Run the test".  it worked for me

Comment: @JohnHenckel: Gotcha. Thanks. Will do that. In fact Schaliasos says exactly that right in his answer; not sure how I missed it.

Comment: There is a `Tests` output window, how do you write to this instead of `Debug`?

Comment: You can get this to the test output if you run `dotnet test -l "console;verbosity=detailed"`. https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/799#issuecomment-1003819952

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution of my own. I know that Andras answer is probably the most consistent with MSTEST, but I didn't feel like refactoring my code.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void OneIsOne()
{
    using (ConsoleRedirector cr = new ConsoleRedirector())
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(cr.ToString().Contains("New text"));
        /* call some method that writes "New text" to stdout */
        Assert.IsTrue(cr.ToString().Contains("New text"));
    }
}
```

The disposable `ConsoleRedirector` is defined as:

```
internal class ConsoleRedirector : IDisposable
{
    private StringWriter _consoleOutput = new StringWriter();
    private TextWriter _originalConsoleOutput;
    public ConsoleRedirector()
    {
        this._originalConsoleOutput = Console.Out;
        Console.SetOut(_consoleOutput);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.SetOut(_originalConsoleOutput);
        Console.Write(this.ToString());
        this._consoleOutput.Dispose();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._consoleOutput.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I was "Running" the tests. If I instead "Debug" the tests the Debug output shows just fine like all others Trace and Console.
I don't know though how to see the output if you "Run" the tests.

Comment: I can get something to show using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` while debugging tests, but how do you get `Console.WriteLine` to work? This doesn't end up in the normal (live updated) output for me.

Comment: Did you find any ways of seeing outputs while running tests?

Answer (score 5):

It's not the console, but it is in the output panel.

```
public class Test
{
 public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

 [TestMethod]
 public void Foo()
 {
   TestContext.WriteLine("Hello World");
 }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**Update**: Load Tests functionality is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2022).

--- original answer
You better setup a single test and create a performance test from this test. This way you can monitor the progress using the default tool set.

Comment: "This way you can monitor the progress using the default tool set." - how? The problem I'm seeing is exactly that once a test runs, it is a black box and I only get to see the output (that I am gradually writing while the test is running) after the test has finished running, in the *Output* window.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release#create-a-load-test