# How to Console.WriteLine from [TestMethod]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing

I am trying to show some information from a [TestMethod] method.

Usually we use NUnit and a line with `Console.WriteLine` runs fine and we can see it in 'output' window, but on this project we must to use Testing tools embebed with VS2010 and `Console.WriteLine` doesn't run because we cannot see anything.

What I want is show trace messages on the 'Output' Window in this way more or less:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;


namespace Test1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestNum1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Constructors()
        {
            for (int b = 1; b < 99; b++) {
                Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());  // <<<<<<< This don't show on Output.
                Assert.AreEqual(b, b);  // This is only a silly sample.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Sorry my duplicate question but I must add a note:  You must execute your Tests in Debug-mode or you cannot see  any output.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you should replace `Console.WriteLine` with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)`

and you will see the output in the Visual Studio Debug Output Window.

**Edit:** just found out now this is a duplicated question, look here:

[How to write to Console.Out during execution of an MSTest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884043/how-to-write-to-console-out-during-execution-of-an-mstest-test)

Comment: Hi @Davide Piras, I have changed `Console.WriteLine` with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` but I cannot still see anything in my output window.

Comment: Ok.. I have seen I MUST to execute Tests in debug-mode or I cannot see anything.

Comment: You must execute your tests in debug-mode if and only if you are using Debug.WriteLine - if using Trace.WriteLine you may use any build flavour - including release

Comment: Thanks @rudolf_franek but I cannot get it to show anything with `Trace.WriteLine`. It only shows text in Debug mode (like `Debug.WriteLine`).  Sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Davide Piras is right - use Trace.Listeners.Add to add existing listener type or create your own type if you need something really special. Easiest standard way is: Trace.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener());

Comment: It seems easy, but it doesn't run for me.  I cannot see anything in my Output Window.  There, in my Ouput Window, I can only select `Build` and no other option.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `testContextInstance.WriteLine(string s);`

Comment: Would be very nice to know where that should come from.

Comment: @Akku, just add `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }` to your class. The test runner populates it for you. You can also receive it as a parameter for your `ClassInitialize` and `AssemblyInitialize` methods.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Outputted text straight to the test results window- perfect!

Comment: This is what I wanted. It shows up in the Test Explorers Output window ( Output link at bottom of VS Test Explorer).

Comment: @Sam having the TextContext property getter/setter is really an answer.  too bad its buried as a comment

Answer (score 5):

You can force the display of `Console.WriteLine()` by running `MSTest` command line with option `/detail:stdout`.

for example:

```
MSTEST /testcontainer:MyDllToTest.dll /testSettings.local.TestSettings /detail:stdout
```

(note I use `/testSettings` to prevent DLL copy (deployment) in a testResults directory