# Can I modify the mstest console output?

Tags: .net, console, mstest, verbosity

I've got some unit tests that I run like this:

```
mstest /testcontainer:"Tests.dll"
```

Is there any way for me to modify, or add to, the output of this command? I've tried Console.Writeline and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884043/how-to-write-to-console-out-during-execution-of-an-mstest-test), but neither seemed to work.

Comment: All the output is redirected from the console and other outputstreams to the trx file. Why do you need this output on stdout?

Comment: Doing a project for school that requires verbose output on the console.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Console.Writeline` as you already do, and run `MSTest` with the [/detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#detail) switch:

```
MSTest /testcontainer:"Tests.dll" /detail:stdout
```

**Code**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output to console...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This is weird, in my case I can see the output.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. I'll give it another shot this evening.

Comment: I *sometimes* get something in the console. But also never all output from all testruns. MSTest is freaking me out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this from the console, but usually I use the TestContext in Visual Studio.  You can use it like String.Format as well.  In Visual Studio you can then go to view test results and see the output.

```
   public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

   [TestMethod]
   public void MyTestMethod()
   {
       int value = 5;
       TestContext.WriteLine("This is my output for the test: {0}", value);
   }
```