# Unit tests missing output in VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

**EDIT:**

I might have found a possible lead.

Checking my **Test Runs** it would seem as if I have 0 completed runs (even though all my 15 tests complete). Any clues?

---

I've got a technical interview coming up where testing will be the main focus. I've got rather limited exposure to testing in Visual Studio and can't seem to figure out why my version (VS2017) won't display the **output** button when I run tests.

Since my limited exposure I've been following along a few PluralSight courses on the subject and have found a decent one covering both LINQ and VS's own unit testing framework.

This is where it should be on VS2015 (I think?):[image]

And this is how it looks for me:

[image]

As you can see I'm missing the **output** button for some god forsaken reason. I've looked in multiple windows (output's debug and tests), but simply cannot see the output.

My unit test follows the instructor's structure with some small changes (like how I set up my `TestContext`, which follows the structure of **[this answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4787047/5986941)**.

This is my unit test:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ACM.Library.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BuilderTest
    {
        private TestContext _testContextInstance;
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return _testContextInstance; }
            set { _testContextInstance = value; }
        } 
        public Builder listBuilder { get; set; }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize ()
        {
            this.listBuilder = new Builder();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestBuildIntegerSequence()
        {
            var result = listBuilder.BuildIntegerSequence();

            foreach(var item in result)
            {
                TestContext.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the function I'm testing...

```
    public IEnumerable<int> BuildIntegerSequence()
    {
        var integers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
        return integers;
    }
```

Comment: Just to rule out some unlikely class/function mixup; do you get output if you reduce the test to a single line, something like `TestContext.WriteLine("Test");`?

Comment: Yeah, no change at all... Thanks tho!

Comment: are you set to release by any chance? instead of debug. I've found where that was an issue on another site.

Comment: Yep, definitely set to debug...

Comment: Hmm, maybe package up a simple example sln? Although it sounds environment related.

Comment: hopefully this answer will help you as it did me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444287/7264254