# Couldn't run tests after updating TestFramework in NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017, mstest

`An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Constructor on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.UnitTestRunner' not found.`

Comment: Next time before posting please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
You need to say what you did, how you tried to solve and info you've been able to gather to receive proper help.

Comment: What the OP probably did was running tests alright. The test framework was probably the one that comes with VS. Then s/he updated the test framework and got an error in the Output pane. At least that is what I did. Then I followed the instructions [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444287/521554) and the problem was resolved.

Comment: I have the same issue when I run my builds in build server.

Answer (score 19):

- Exit Visual Studio.
- Delete %temp%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions
- Restart Visual Studio and try again.
- That's all it was.

Comment: Although I've the same question as @JasonV it did help me, so thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while running tests in the build server.

I tried below things and it started working:

- updated my projects to point to latest **MSTest.TestAdapter** and **MSTest.TestFramework**
- cleared old versions of **MSTest.TestAdapter** and **MSTest.TestFramework** folders from build server under this paths

  C:\Users\.nuget\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter
   C:\Users\.nuget\packages\MSTest.TestFramework
- I cleared the source files in the build once(not sure about this step but worth trying just in case)